# MySQL: transaction not rolled back

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

doing a simple transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO users_trips VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO users_trips VALUES ('1', '41'); <-- this fails due to foreign key contraints
COMMIT;
```

however, the first record is persisted. I am using InnoDB engine.

```
mysql> show create table users_trips;
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Table       | Create Table
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| users_trips | CREATE TABLE `users_trips` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trip_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`trip_id`),
  KEY `users_trips_trip_id_fk` (`trip_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_trips_trip_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`trip_id`) REFERENCES `trips`     (`trip_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_trips_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why isn't it rolled back?

thanks

Comment: You did not rollback upon hitting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a COMMIT on your transactions. even if one of the transaction fails before commit, the others will be commited. You would need to issue ROLLBACK in this case.